# Manually calling document.ready

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dom-events

Is there a way to force the event `document.ready` to fire through Javascript? The new Rails 4 default of using [turbo links](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) by default kills this event from firing when switching pages. This causes problems with more 'traditional' jQuery code that is wrapped in `$(function(){});`.

I've taken a look around and don't see any way of making this event fire through code and most answers on here offer other work-arounds.

So is it even possible to make document.ready fire through regular Javascript code?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using jQuery then?  If you are, try an explicit call to Jquery's [`$.ready();`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)  function at the end of your code.  This will force *all* jQuery "ready" functions to be called, both your own and those in any plugins you're using.

If that doesn't work, you can try [`$(window).load();`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

If neither of those work and you're using some type of asynchronous call, you probably have some other issue to weed out first. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do this without a big change on your code is to listen to a custom event instead of ready and inside the ready event fire the custom event.

Answer (score 1):

From the [turbolinks documentation](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#events):
You have to make the document listen to one of the turbolinks custom page events, for example:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution:

Insert your Gemfile this:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Insert your application.js this:

```
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```

(Don't forget a `bundle update`)

If you have in your coffescript code the following it will be triggered for full page reload or for opening a page via link when turbolinks is active:

```
$ ->
   alert 'Hello World'
```

(`$ ->` means `document.ready`)